# Error message of embree and ospray on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I encountered errors while installing SCIRun5 (with Qt4.8.4) on Ubuntu 16.04. The errors seem to be related to ospray and embree (most updated version), as follows:

```
CMake Error at cmake/ospray_macros.cmake:45 (message):
  We did not find Embree installed on your system.  OSPRay requires an Embree
  installation >= v3.1.0, please download and extract Embree (or compile
  Embree from source), then set the 'embree_DIR' variable to the installation
  (or build) directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/configure_embree.cmake:20 (ospray_find_embree)
  cmake/ospray_options.cmake:109 (INCLUDE)
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (INCLUDE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/George/SCIRun/bin/Externals/Build/Ospray_external/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMakeFiles/Ospray_external.dir/build.make:106: recipe for target 'Externals/Stamp/Ospray_external/Ospray_external-configure' failed
make[2]: *** [Externals/Stamp/Ospray_external/Ospray_external-configure] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:739: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Ospray_external.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Ospray_external.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Building SCIRun returned an error
```

Actually, I’ve installed embree according to https://embree.github.io/downloads.html

```
sudo alien embree3-lib-3.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo alien embree3-devel-3.2.0-1.noarch.rpm
sudo alien embree3-examples-3.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

sudo dpkg -i embree3-lib_3.2.0-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i embree3-devel_3.2.0-2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i embree3-examples_3.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

At terminal, however, nothing appears when I input “embree” or "locate embree*". Could you please guide me what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. In detail, I installed another version of SCIRun5 and qt4-opengl.